# Querying a module for a list of functions/types

Tags: haskell, emacs

I am new to haskell and I recently installed emacs with haskell-mode and I am wondering if it is somehow possible to query a namespace to get a list of functions/types?

For example if I do

```
import qualified Graphics.UI.GLFW as G
```

and then

```
G.
```

It would be nice to see what data is inside of G. Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're in GHCi, you can use

```
> :browse Grahics.UI.GLFW
```

If otherwise, there's several modules out there than can perform this functionality.  I don't know of any plugins specific to emacs, but in Sublime Text I use the SublimeHaskell plugin which uses ghc-mod, hdevtools, and a few other packages installable from cabal to provide that sort of functionality.

Comment: You can shorten `:browse` to just `:bro`

Answer (score 2):

I do not program in haskell (but I do use emacs), a bit of googling lead to [this](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Emacs) page which has some tips for using emacs for haskell, which you may find it useful. [Emacs frontend](http://www.mew.org/~kazu/proj/ghc-mod/en/emacs.html) to ghc-mod might provide the feature you are looking for. [Scion](https://github.com/nominolo/scion) also looks interesting.